# Remove Exif data from image when using Imagesharp.web

Tags: imagesharp

I'm using imagesharp.web. Image width/height is reduced as expected, but size not reduced to fit for web applications(Size is more that 1 MB). I found that Exif data are there in the image contributing to this size.

Is there a way to remove Exif data from a image when we use Imagesharp.web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Metadata.ExifProfile` property to `null` during [OnBeforeSaveAsync](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp.Web/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Middleware.ImageSharpMiddlewareOptions.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Web_Middleware_ImageSharpMiddlewareOptions_OnBeforeSaveAsync)

```cs
services.AddImageSharp(
    options => options.OnBeforeSaveAsync = f =>
    {
        f.Image.Metadata.ExifProfile = null;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
```